# Java regex question

Tags: java, regex

I have a text something like

```
ab1ab2ab3ab4cd
```

Can one create a java regular expression to obtain all subtrings that start with `"ab"` and end with `"cd"`? e.g:

```
ab1ab2ab3ab4cd
ab2ab3ab4cd
ab3ab4cd
ab4cd
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The regex `(?=(ab.*cd))` will group such matches in group 1 as you can see:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(ab.*cd))").matcher("ab1ab2ab3ab4cd");

    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```

which produces:

```
ab1ab2ab3ab4cd
ab2ab3ab4cd
ab3ab4cd
ab4cd
```

You need the look ahead, `(?= ... )`, otherwise you'll just get one match. Note that regex will fail to produce the desired results if there are more than 2 `cd`'s in your string. In that case, you'll have to resort to some manual string algorithm.

Comment: For my curiozity, for the "reversed" case how should look the rx? String is ab1cd2cd3cd, and I want ab1cd, ab1cd2cd, ab1cd2cd3cd

Comment: @Dudu, you can't do that with regex: the regex-engine evaluates from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want either `ab\w+?cd` or `\bab\w+?cd\b`

Comment: I suspect the second is more along the lines of what he wants - or more realistically what he needs.

Comment: So how will you get all substrings that match this pattern?

Comment: No, that will find just one substring.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. You could still find all substrings by repeatedly calling `find` with an offset just beyond the start of the last match, but Bart's solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^ab[a-z0-9]+cd$/gm
```

If only `a` `b` `c` and `digits 0-9` can appear in the middle as in the examples:

```
/^ab[a-c\d]+cd$/gm
```

**See it in action:** http://regexr.com?2tpdu

Comment: That will just match/validate a single string, but the OP asked if there's a regex that matches _all_ (sub) strings that match a particular pattern.

Comment: @Bart I'm unfamiliar with Java, does it have a global & multiline modifier?

Comment: Nope, no global modifier. You'll have to traverse all possible matches yourself, and once a (sub) pattern has been matched, it cannot be a part of another match: that's why I used the zero-width look-ahead in my answer.